# How do I reduce/eliminate data imports in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am a software developer that is new to the Power BI world.  I have inherited a project that is making use of Power BI Desktop as a reporting platform to leverage the ability to generate ad hoc reports, including graphics.

We are using SqlServer 2016 as the data source.  The data utilized for the reports is stored in the database as xml text.  The xml is provided by a vendor and stored in the database.  We want to read the xml from the database into XMLDATA, then decompose that into data tables (30+ tables) using queries.  The XMLDATA data table is set to DirectQuery storage mode.  All of the decomposed tables are set to Import storage mode with the query source set to XMLDATA.

When a refresh is done, each of the decomposed data table's data is being imported, which is taking a long time (2+ hours for 17500 xml records, and this is a small test set of records).  It seems as though Power BI Desktop is reading all of the database rows for each of the tables instead of using the XMLDATA read in from the database.  Is there a way to set up the decomposed tables so they use the XMLDATA instead of importing for each table?  We are only using Power BI Desktop and none of the other Power BI products/services.

Comment: Thoughts about using calculated tables for your subset of 30+ tables? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-calculated-tables

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Calculated tables use DAX functions for creation.  The queries currently used to create the decomposed tables use M Language, which has functionality to expand the XML in a column into multiple columns based on the XML structure.  Not sure how to accomplish this with the calculated tables and DAX.

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you update your original post with screenshots of your current setup, redacting any information you do not want public.